# In 1st Corinthians 11:7, is it the image that covers the head?

Tags: 1-corinthians, grammar

What connects to what in this verse?

> **1 Corinthians 11:7** (Stephanus Textus Receptus 1550)
>   ἀνὴρ μὲν γὰρ οὐκ ὀφείλει κατακαλύπτεσθαι τὴν κεφαλήν, εἰκὼν καὶ δόξα θεοῦ ὑπάρχων· γυνὴ δὲ δόξα ἀνδρός ἐστιν·

As best I can figure the main parts here are:

- εἰκὼν The Nominative [image](http://biblehub.com/greek/1504.htm) (guessing nominative based on ν)
- κατακαλύπτεσθαι The Verb [cover](http://biblehub.com/greek/2619.htm) (guessing verb on no understanding)
- κεφαλήν The Accusative [head](http://biblehub.com/greek/2776.htm) (guessing accusative based on ν)

Is it correct from this to assert that it is the image that covers the head?

Additionally, since κεφαλήν acts as only Accusative noun in the verse:

- What Nominative Noun acts as the Subject to the Accusative?
- What Verb "acts upon" the Accusative?
- Considering only the Nominative, Verb, and Accusative how would that be best translated?
- Using this knowledge could a personal translation of 1 Cor 11:7 be built?
- Do any of [these translations](http://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/11-7.htm) take into account the Nominative and Accusative Case?
- If it does, then how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

---

## 1. Question Restatement

In [1 Corinthians 11:7, Interlinear with Inflected Analysis](http://biblehub.com/interlinear/1_corinthians/11-7.htm) - ***What is the proper [inflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection) analysis for the clause***:

> To cover, head, image

---

## 2. Clarifications:

A writer does not always have to rely on the "Accusative Case" to show which object the verb is acting on.

In this case, the writer is using "[Apposition](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0007:id=s916)", (using a noun to describe another noun) - ***the attributive noun must agree in case***, (Nominative must match Nominative);

> [Smyth grammar 4.34.64](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0007%3Apart%3D4%3Achapter%3D34%3Asection%3D64): **976.** Concord.—An appositive (916) agrees in case with the word it describes.  **991.** Apposition to a Sentence.—A noun in the nominative or accusative may stand in apposition to the action expressed by a whole sentence or by some part of it. **a.** The appositive is nominative when a nominative precedes: ...

---

## 3. Quick Answers:

1. **Question:** Is it the image that covers the head?

   - **Answer:** No - "image" and "Cover" are separated - and in distinct clauses, associated with two different verbs.
2. **Question:** What Nominative Noun acts as the Subject to the Accusative?

   - **Clause 1:** Subject/Nominative = "**Man**"; Verb = "**Cover**"; Object/Accusative = "**Head**";
   - **Clause 2:**  Subject/Nominative = "**Image and Glory**"; Verb = "**Already Being**"; Object = "**Man**", (via Participle Phrase + Apposition)
   - **Clause 3:**  Subject/Nominative = "**Woman**"; Verb = "**Is**"; Object = "**Glory of Man**", (via Apposition);
3. **Question:** What Verb "acts upon" the Accusative? ***See #2.***
4. **Question:** Considering only the Nominative, Verb, and Accusative how would that be best translated?

   > **Paraphrase 1:** "There really is no religious obligation for a head-covering - ***because man is already the image and Glory of God***.
5. **Question:** Using this knowledge could a personal translation of 1 Cor 11:7 be built? ***Below.***
6. **Question:** Do any of these translations take into account the Nominative and Accusative Case? If it does, then how? ***See #2.***

---

## 4. Creating a Translation - Relying on the Interpretation of "ὑπάρχων"

The reason the question can be asked in the first place, is that the verb, "ὑπάρχων" is misunderstood - ***ὑπάρχων does not mean "to be"***.

***[ὑπάρχων, (Lexicon)](http://biblehub.com/greek/5225.htm)*** denotes "***Already***", or literally: "***From the Beginning***".

> "The image and glory .. ***is already"*** - [Man].

***Note:*** **ὑπάρχων** is usually always equated with "To Be" verbs in the Testament, ([New Testament Search Results](http://biblehub.com/greek/uparcho_n_5225.htm)).

**A Different Translation:**

In this case - the clarification significantly alters the interpretation of the verse.

> **1 Corinthians 11:7** - A man really isn't obligated to cover his head; because [a man] is already an image and glory of God.

***Note:*** In many cases - parts of sentences are elided/omitted, because the writer believes the reader can reasonably infer what the missing word is, ("[a man]", in this case).

**In other words:**

> **Paraphrase 2:** "Man" is already as dressed up as he can be - therefore, there is no religious obligation to decorate himself further with a [kippah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kippah).

---

## 5. Is Already / ὑπάρχων - A Temporal Participle:

Verbs that are Participles can fulfill many purposes, ([Grammar, Participle Functions](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0052%3Aform%3Dpart));

**Analyzing the Participle Phrase:**

1. **ὑπάρχων**: **A.)** Is a Verb, Participle, derived from "ὑπάρχω", [New Testament Search](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/perseus-cgi/search3torth?dbname=GreekFeb2011&word=lemma%3A%E1%BD%91%CF%80%CE%AC%CF%81%CF%87%CF%89&OUTPUT=kwic&ORTHMODE=ORG&CONJUNCT=PHRASE&DISTANCE=3&author=&title=New%20Testament&POLESPAN=5&THMPRTLIMIT=1&KWSS=1&KWSSPRLIM=500&trsortorder=author%2C%20title&editor=&pubdate=&language=&shrtcite=&filename=&genre=&sortorder=author%2C%20title&dgdivhead=&dgdivtype=&dgsubdivwho=&dgsubdivn=&dgsubdivtag=&dgsubdivtype=); **B.)** The context indicates it is not a noun, and not derived from "ὕπαρχος", a noun - and never seems to be used by Paul this way, ([New Testament Search](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/showrest_?kwic.6.1.94331.0.14.GreekFeb2011)); **C.)** Possibly [Genitive Absolute](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Smyth%20grammar%202070&lang=original), but ultimately not materially relevant;
2. **Temporal Participle:** The preposition prefix, (ὕπ,"under"), indicating "Previously", and also from the beginning, (αρχος, first / beginning);
3. **Circumstantial Participle:** Denoting a justification in the context of a logical argument.

Comment: That was wonderful!!! It was stated: "image" and "Cover" are separated into two clauses. What indicates that a clause is in effect?

Comment: @Decrypted - What identifies the two/three clauses? **A.) THREE different clauses identified by Subjects in the Nominative Case:** 1.) "Man"; 2.) "Glory and Image"; and 3.) "Woman"; **B.)** Likewise, three different predicates - verbs - "Cover", "Already being", "Is"; **C.)** The first clause is independent - everything is there: `"Man, Cover, Head"`; **D.)** The Second Clause is dependent on the first - for "Man" **E.)** The third clause is independent like the first: `"Woman, is, Glory of Man"` **F.)** And the third clause reinforces what the second clause is: `"Man, already, Glory of God"`;

Comment: @Decrypted - I updated this answer - a lot; **A.)** I added references to ***"Apposition"*** to show that "Direct Objects" don't really have to be in the "Accusative Case" - but can also be Nominative, etc; **B.)** I added clarification regarding the distinct clauses - and added the third clause in for clarification. **C.)** By no means am I an expert in Greek Syntax - but I believe the grammars referenced support the conclusion, here.